# Jenkins fails on checkout

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a jenkins file where I build different stages successfully. However when I try to build my testautomation on a different agent (windows device) like this:

```
    stage("Neem Testautomation") {
        parallel {
            stage('build testautomation/neem') {
                agent { label 'windows-test-device' }

                steps {
                    bat '''
                    // different operations before build
                    C:\\Jenkins\\apache-maven-3.6.3\\bin\\mvn test'''
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It checks out the repository to the test device but fails upon checking out (see error below). I figured the Jenkins does this checkout automatically on a new agent but I'm trying to figure out why it fails. I tried cloning the repository locally on the windows machine and it works just fine.

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
git config remote.origin.url https://repositoryName.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://repositoryName.git
git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHub Enterprise Access Token
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- https://repositoryName.git +refs/heads/development:refs/remotes/origin/development # timeout=120
Checking out Revision a82361154ae69cff94c9f3df1d719c25935a3b32 (development)
git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
git checkout -f a82361154ae69cff94c9f3df1d719c25935a3b32
Could not checkout a82361154ae69cff94c9f3df1d719c25935a3b32
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the pipeline? Is there a option{}-section declared?

Comment: No option section declared so far. What else do you need?:)

Comment: Where in that `Jenkinsfile` would the `git` actions occur?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering too. I assumed it does it automatically on new agents? Maybe there's something setup in jenkins configuartions but so far I can't really tell.

Comment: are you using Jenkinsfile with a Multibranch Pipeline?

Comment: No I don't use multibranch pipeline

Comment: the git tool location is configured for the windows agent you are running? Git bin dir is included in 'Path' environment variable?

Comment: Yes otherwise it would not recognize the git command.

Comment: What is the exception that it throws after the line - Could not checkout ...?

Comment: None - that’s all I get. I’m using the ocean blue plugin.

Comment: Probably the console log from classic UI can reveal more secrets? What I suspect is that Jenkins logs in as a different user than you use to log in manually, and it might not be finding git in the path. Without the stack trace after the last line, it’s difficult to tell. What you can try is to skip default checkout in your Jenkinsfile and only run `git --version` on that agent. The output will make things clearer.