# Jenkins bitbucket.org checkout using x-auth-token fails with GitException error 128 on a particular node

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

## TL/DR

I looked at [Why is Jenkins failing when fetching from git, while the command line isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813816/why-is-jenkins-failing-when-fetching-from-git-while-the-command-line-isnt), [Jenkins fails on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095091/jenkins-fails-on-checkout) and various other search results.

### Error

On one Jenkins node checkout of a bitbucket.org repo fails. On several other nodes, the exact same checkout succeeds. The nodes are connected to the same Jenkins controller.
The x-auth-token is stored in the credential manager on the controller.

`hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:`

## Extra info

- git clone from the command line, using the same credentials, the same linux user it succeeds.
- The same job on a different linux host with the same Jenkins plugin version succeeds.
- The error occurred in a scripted jenkinsfile
- I created a simple free-style job that just does the checkout and it shows the same error, logging below is from that simple job.

I added `GIT_TRACE=1` to the environment to get some extra logging.

### Succesful log on node company-dev02

```
Started by user User name
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
GIT_TRACE=1

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building remotely on company-dev02 (developmenthost linuxreleasehost linux latest22_linux_db test22cloud_linux_db test22_linux_db develop23_linux_db develop_linux_db) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cceadm appltest22/xcomp checkout company-dev02
[EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'BASH_FUNC_which%%' variable.
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential tokentokenTOKENTOKEN
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cceadm appltest22/xcomp checkout company-dev02 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.31.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials token TOKENTOKEN
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/xcomp/22.0/test^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse xcomp/22.0/test^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84 (refs/remotes/origin/xcomp/22.0/test)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Merge branch 'user/config/company-812-Cloud-build' into xcomp/22.0/test"
 > git rev-list --no-walk e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84 # timeout=10
18:51:17.933383 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git whatchanged --no-abbrev -M '--format=commit %H%ntree %T%nparent %P%nauthor %aN <%aE> %ai%ncommitter %cN <%cE> %ci%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B' -n 1024 e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84 ^e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential tokentokenTOKENTOKEN
 > git rev-parse e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84^{commit} # timeout=10
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential tokentokenTOKENTOKEN
[GitCheckoutListener] Recording commits of 'git https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git'
[GitCheckoutListener] Found previous build 'cceadm appltest22/xcomp checkout company-dev02 #2' that contains recorded Git commits
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Starting recording of new commits since 'e7ce93e'
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Multiple parent commits found - storing latest commit of local merge 'e7ce93e'
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Using parent commit '05cef30' of local merge as starting point
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Storing target branch head '74f329b' (second parent of local merge) 
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Recorded 200 new commits
[GitCheckoutListener] -> The latest commit 'e7ce93ef07cdaff3ae372dfed57c93ccf3ebbd84' is a merge commit
[GitCheckoutListener] -> Git commit decorator successfully obtained 'hudson.plugins.git.browser.BitbucketWeb@72f603c0' to render commit links
Finished: SUCCESS
```

### Failed log

```
Started by user User name
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
GIT_TRACE=1

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building remotely on company-admdb (applprod22_linux_db linux appltest22_linux_db) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cceadm appltest22/xcomp checkout
[EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'BASH_FUNC_which%%' variable.
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential tokentokenTOKENTOKEN
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cceadm appltest22/xcomp checkout # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.31.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials token TOKENTOKEN
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: 18:54:05.328181 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
18:54:05.328405 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git https://x-token-auth:*******************************************************************************************@bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
18:54:05.330301 git.c:733               trace: exec: git-remote-https https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git https://x-token-auth:*******************************************************************************************@bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
18:54:05.330335 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git-remote-https https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git https://x-token-auth:*******************************************************************************************@bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git
remote: The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/company/reponame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2842)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:635)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:871)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:170)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to company-admdb
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2090.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:138)
        at jdk.proxy123/jdk.proxy123.$Proxy256.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1222)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1248)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:649)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:521)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1895)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: `The requested URL returned error: 403` stands out for me here. Is there another set of credentials that that one host might be using? 403 indicates that the credentials themselves are valid, but that the associated account doesn't have permission to do the requested action.

Comment: I started of with credentials that work on all nodes, except the one where it is failing. I also created new tokens. The credentials work when I select them in the  Jenkins web interface. If I use the url from the failed logging in a git clone from the commandline its fails. So I have a something  to investigate but no solution yet. @JimRedmond thank you for pointing me in the right direction. 
It would be nice if I could get the full URL from the successful job, but only logs that on failure

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I don't know what the chances are that some-one will run into the same cause of this problem, but I'll post the solution anyway.

At some point in the past `git config insteadof` was set up for the user that runs the jenkins agent, see [How to convert `git:` urls to `http:` urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/how-to-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls/11383587#11383587).
It was added to insert token authentication behind the scenes using

```
git config --global url."https://x-token-auth:sometoken@bitbucket.org".insteadOf https://bitbucket.org
```

The token that was used there was valid for some repos, but not for all.

Removing the config using `git config --global -e` solved the issue.
Thanks to @jim-redmond for his comment pointing me in the right direction.